# Groovy- Not able to use size() or length functions on an array -Oracle Sales Cloud

Tags: java, groovy

> The part in the loop where I am using the size function is not working. I have tried to use the length function as well.

```
The error that I get is Size() is not available for Java.Lang.String
```

String cPersonFirstName = nvl(PersonFirstName, '');

```
String[] substringsNoSpace = cPersonFirstName.split(" ");


println ("This is the output  " + substringsNoSpace );

String message = ''
for (int i = 0; **i <SubstringsNoSpace.size()** ; i++) {

  Integer x = substringsNoSpace[i].length();
  def currentWord=substringsNoSpace[i] ;
  println ("  "+ x+ "  " + currentWord )
  message +=  substringsNoSpace[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(substringsNoSpace[i].substring(1, x).toLowerCase())+ " ";

}


println (message);



setAttribute ('PersonFirstName',message );
```

Comment: provided code doesn't look like real code. but if you'll provide valid code, a real code that throws this error, then we'll be able to help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.. this is the real code i am using..this is my first question on stackoverflow.. request you to please help me understand the format of the code you are looking for

Comment: this code simply invalid, I cannot compile it. you have array in `substringsNoSpace` variable, but using `SubstringsNoSpace` for loop. No information about second variable, but error says that last one is a `String`, not `String[]`. Also, `**i <SubstringsNoSpace.size()**` is invalid notation, you probably mean `i <SubstringsNoSpace.size()`. And finally, error says that you've called `Size()` method, but code have `size()`, which is correct?

Comment: And there's no such package in java: `Java.Lang.String`.

Comment: Below is the exact error-   Exception in expression "PersonDEO" trigger "DT_FirstNameCapsCreate" : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException : No such property: lenght for class: [Ljava.lang.String; Possible solutions: length
at "PersonDEO" trigger "DT_FirstNameCapsCreate" line 15

Error 
No such property: lenght for class: [Ljava.lang.String; Possible solutions: length......

Comment: String cPersonFirstName = nvl(PersonFirstName, '');


String[] substringsNoSpace = cPersonFirstName.split(" ");


println ("This is the output  " + substringsNoSpace );

String message = ''
for (int i = 0; i <substringsNoSpace.lenght ; i++) {
 
  Integer x = substringsNoSpace[i].length();
  def currentWord=substringsNoSpace[i] ;
  println ("  "+ x+ "  " + currentWord )
  message +=  substringsNoSpace[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(substringsNoSpace[i].substring(1, x).toLowerCase())+ " ";
  
}


println (message);

setAttribute ('PersonFirstName',message );

Comment: as you see from error message `Possible solutions: length`, instead of current `.lenght`

Answer (score 1):

That's not the same variable you're modifying...

You declared `substringsNoSpace` with lowercase `s` and you're trying to modify `SubstringsNoSpace` with capital `s`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Igor Artamonov, but I believe your issue is in for:

for (int i = 0; i  ; i++) {

SubstringsNoSpace is an array, so you should use SubstringsNoSpace.length

Comment: Hi Grady, thanks for the quick response.. yes the problem is in the loop part only, the problem is when i give  SubstringsNoSpace.length then it throws an error which says length function cannot be used with Java.lang.String

Comment: String cPersonFirstName = nvl(PersonFirstName, '');
String[] substringsNoSpace = cPersonFirstName.split(" ");

String message = ''
for (int i = 0; i <substringsNoSpace.lenght ; i++) {
 
  Integer x = substringsNoSpace[i].length();
  def currentWord=substringsNoSpace[i] ;
  println ("  "+ x+ "  " + currentWord )
  message +=  substringsNoSpace[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(substringsNoSpace[i].substring(1, x).toLowerCase())+ " ";
  
}


println (message);

setAttribute ('PersonFirstName',message );

Answer (score 0):

In more groovy way, your code could look like:

```
String cPersonFirstName = nvl(PersonFirstName, '') 
String[] substringsNoSpace = cPersonFirstName.split(' ') 
println "This is the output $substringsNoSpace"

String message = substringsNoSpace.collect {
  println "${it.length()} $it"
  it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + it.su‌​bstring(1).toLowerCase()  
  //btw, it can be replaced with this:
  //it.capitalize()       
}.join(' ')

println message 
setAttribute ('PersonFirstName', message)
```